# document.getElementById(fieldName).value; is not working in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamics-crm

Following javascript in HTML is working in IE browser. But, when i execute in Chrome and Firefox browser is not working.

```
var LastName = GetValueofField("txtName");

function GetValueofField(fieldName)
    {
        return document.getElementById(fieldName).value;
    }
```

please help me.

Comment: getElementById requires element's id. Are you passing element's name?

Comment: Works fine for me. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/85ce6nLx/)

Comment: @Henrik is correct, if you are writing form script it is not supported to use document.getElementById, you should instead be going through the Xrm library function Xrm.Page.getAttribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working fine...

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ritesh14887/cw6uwo93/1/)

```
<input type="text" id="txtName" value="TestData">

var LastName = GetValueofField("txtName");
function GetValueofField(fieldName)
    {
    console.log(document.getElementById(fieldName).value)
        return document.getElementById(fieldName).value;
    }
```

Comment: While it may work (at the time of this posting), this is not supported in Dynamics CRM @Henrik's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

It is not supported by Microsoft to use `document.getElementById` in Dynamics CRM.

Instead you should use the following supported function the get the value of a field on a form:

[Xrm.Page.getAttribute(arg).getValue()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334409.aspx#Anchor_15)

Answer (score 0):

You can access element by `getElementById` with only element Id, so pass proper Id of element in function:

```js
var LastName = GetValueofField("txtId");
console.log(LastName)
function GetValueofField(fieldName)
{
   return document.getElementById(fieldName).value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtId" name="txtName" value="Test"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments you need to input the ID of your input control.

Your html input would look like:

```
<input type="text" id="txtUsername" />
```

Then your Javascript to retrieve the value:

```
var name = document.getElementById("txtUsername").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Working fine for me !!! , Check your html code and JavaScript for typo.

```js
var LastName = GetValueofField("txtName");

function GetValueofField(fieldName)
    {
      console.log(fieldName);
      console.log(document.getElementById(fieldName).value);
      return document.getElementById(fieldName).value;
    }

function alertme()
{
  console.log(document.getElementById("txtName").value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtName" value='1' onchange=alertme() />
```